# Get ping between countries?

Tags: testing, networking, ping

I need to get ping address between two countries, when I located in third place. Which service do you suggest to decide this task?

Answer (score 1):

If you need the ping time to a server from many different locations, one site is http://www.just-ping.com - this gives the ping time from around 50 places.  There are other similar sites.

Another way is to get a virtual server in country (city) one, and ssh into it, and then ping a server on country two from it.

This also works in reverse.  For example, if you are in Paris but want to know the ping time from Quebec to your server in Dallas, you could ssh into your Dallas server, and ping a site in Quebec.  But using just-ping.com is generally good enough.